# Override parent datacontext

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm learning about databinding at the moment, and facing some trouble with parent and child datacontexts.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
        DataContext="{Binding Group}"
        d:DataContext="{Binding Groups[0], Source={d:DesignData Source=/DataModel/SampleData.json, Type=data:SampleDataSource}}">
        <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


 <StackPanel x:Name="SideData" Width="480" Margin="12,12,24,12" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" DataContext="{Binding SideItem}">
        <TextBlock x:Name="SideText"        Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="12,12,12,12" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" MaxHeight="60"/>
        <Image x:Name="SideImage"           Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Height="400" Width="400"  Margin="0,0,0,20" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="SideDescription" Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Margin="0,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

I want to leave the DataContext for the Grid at "Group", but I want all the controls inside the StackPanel to be bound to "SideItem".

I'm sure I've done it wrong as it isn't working properly. When I bind the Grid's datacontext to "SideItem", it works, but that changes the whole thing, so it's pretty pointless. Help?

Also, here is the backend (I'm using the Visual Studio 2013 template):

```
private async void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: Create an appropriate data model for your problem domain to replace the sample data
    var group = await SampleDataSource.GetGroupAsync((String)e.NavigationParameter);
    this.DefaultViewModel["Group"] = group;
    this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = group.Items;
    this.DefaultViewModel["SideItem"] = group.Items.First();
}
```

Comment: If you want controls which are inside of stackpanel were bound to SideItem maybe you will set DataContext of stackpanel to SideItem?

Comment: tried that first... not working.. that's what is confusing me the most

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the datacontext of the stack panel:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding SideItem}" ...
```

Comment: SideItem is on its own, I've edited the code above to what I tried (same as your answer I think?).

Answer (score 0):

It's seems `SideItem` should a property of `Group`, is that right? What is Group in your code?

**EDIT**:

If you want to bind to SideItem which is related to a window, try this:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding SideItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
```

Comment: I realise I could use this: Text="{Binding Items[0].Title}", but can I have SideItem as a completely seperate DataContext?

Comment: @ForeverLearning See, your grid is bound to `Group` instance. When you write `Items[0].Title` then WPF is looking value here: `Group.Items[0].Title` and it is ok. When you write `{Binding SideItem}` WPF is looking property here: `Group.SideItem` and there is no such property! Your group must have property SideItem in this case. Or try write like this: `<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding SideItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">` Because SideItem is related to window I guess (or control).